# Не работает всплывающее сообщение после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qmainwindow, qmessagebox

Программа должна после нажатия на кнопку выводить всплывающее сообщение с текстом и тремя кнопками. 
Но после нажатия на кнопку программа закрывается с ошибкой :

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

Как исправить ее, чтобы правильно работало?

Код программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow


def error():
    error = QMessageBox()
    error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
    error.setText("Ошибка")
    error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
    error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Ignore | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    error.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Ignore)
    error.exec()

def app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(200,200,200,200)
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
    btn.move(70,150)
    btn.clicked.connect(error)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня ваш код на PyQt5 работает правильно. Ответ, который вы приняли, не правильный.

Обратите внимание:

- чтобы получать реальную ошибку, запустите выше приложение терминале/CMD;
- создание [**главного окна**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) без центрального виджета не поддерживается. У вас должен быть центральный виджет, даже если это просто заполнитель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.error)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        
    def error(self):
        error = QMessageBox()
        error.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
        error.setText("Ошибка: 911")
        error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        error.setStandardButtons(
            QMessageBox.Retry | QMessageBox.Ignore | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        error.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Ignore)
        error.exec()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]